# Why i get error when want insert to table in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm beginner in write query,i write this query for insert any data to table:

```
insert into ScoreTable  (UserID,Score,PhoneNumber,date_) 
select id,sum(Duration) / 60 ,phoneNumber,Date_ from CDR p
where p.phoneNumber=phoneNumber
```

but when i execute the that query,i get this error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Column 'CDR.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

How can i solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the select statement. Run that independently and you will get the same issue. Because you're aggregating (`SUM`) you require a `group by` clause. Give this a go;

```
SELECT p.id
    ,sum(p.Duration) / 60
    ,p.phoneNumber
    ,p.Date_
FROM CDR p
WHERE p.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
GROUP BY p.id, p.phoneNumber, p.Date
```

Also remember to use your table aliases in the queries to avoid ambiguity.